# Looking for a regex that match all words, except the ones [inside brackets]

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that matches all word inside a specific string, but skips words inside brackets. I currently have one regex that matches all words:

```
/[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*/i
```

I also have a regex that matches all words inside brackets:

```
/\[(.*)\]/i
```

I basically want to match everything that the first regex matches, but without everything the second regex matches.

Sample input text: http://gist.github.com/222857
It should match every word separately, without the one in the brackets.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So `fine young lady from [Venice][1],` becomes `fine young lady from,`?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could do it in two steps:

1. Remove all the text within brackets.
2. Use a regular expression to match the remaining words.

Using a single regular expression to try to do both these things will end up being more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I'll do too.

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout this:

```
your_text.scan(/\[.*\]|([a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)/i) - [[nil]]
```

Comment: Hey Glenn, you mean and then look at Group 1? That's a cool simple technique that for some reason very few people seem to be using. +1! :) I just used it on a [regex bounty quest](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174) and found your answer while researching if anyone is using the technique.

Answer (score 1):

Which Ruby version are you using?  If it's 1.9 or later, this should do what you want:

```
/(?<![\[a-z0-9-])[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*(?![\]a-z0-9-])/i
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand the question properly. Why not just make a new string that does not contain the second regex like so:

```
string1 =~ s/\[(.*)\]//g
```

Off the top of my head won't that match what you deleted while storing the result in string1? I have not tested this yet though. I might test it later.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Shhnap. Without more info, it sounds like the easiest way is to remove what you don't want. but it needs to be /[(.*?)]/ instead. After that you can split on \s.

If you are trying to iterate through each word, and you want each word to match maybe you can cheat a little with: string.split(/\W+/) .You will lose the quotations and what not, but you get each word.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
[^\[][a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*
```

if the first letter of a word is an opening bracket, it doesnt match it.

btw, is there a reason why you are capturing the words with dashes in them? If no need for that, your regex could be simplified.